# Problems installing Gitlab on odroid (v8 lib not available?)

Tags: ruby, arm, v8, gitlab, odroid

Installing gitlab into my odroid went just fine... Using the steps from https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md until this command

```
sudo -u git -H bundle install --deployment --without development test postgres aws
```

but that just failed to install therubyracer 0.12.0 (actually, what failed was compiling v8, because it requires the -fPIC flag). Here's the error message

```
/usr/bin/ld: /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/arm.release/obj.target/tools/gyp/libv8_base.a(api.o): relocation R_ARM_THM_MOVW_ABS_NC against `a local symbol' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/arm.release/obj.target/tools/gyp/libv8_base.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So... I installed v8 on the system by cloning https://github.com/v8/v8 and doing a checkout of the commit 7ce3fe106a37826dc23189a78dcb9000a1b3fa06 (b/c that's what's used on libv8 on the tag v3.16.14.3 and that's the one Gitlab needs).

The missing flag is -fPIC, so after doing `make dependencies` I did this change (doing it as a patch so that's easier to see... I just added -fPIC whenever -Wall is used)

```
--- build/standalone.gypi.original  2014-02-09 21:58:48.627732201 +0000
+++ build/standalone.gypi   2014-02-09 22:02:27.236682523 +0000
@@ -96,7 +96,7 @@
     ['OS=="linux" or OS=="freebsd" or OS=="openbsd" or OS=="solaris" \
        or OS=="netbsd"', {
       'target_defaults': {
-        'cflags': [ '-Wall', '<(werror)', '-W', '-Wno-unused-parameter',
+        'cflags': [ '-fPIC', '-Wall', '<(werror)', '-W', '-Wno-unused-parameter',
                     '-Wnon-virtual-dtor', '-pthread', '-fno-rtti',
                     '-fno-exceptions', '-pedantic' ],
         'ldflags': [ '-pthread', ],
@@ -206,7 +206,7 @@
             '-fno-strict-aliasing',
           ],
           'WARNING_CFLAGS': [
-            '-Wall',
+            '-fPIC', '-Wall',
             '-Wendif-labels',
             '-W',
             '-Wno-unused-parameter',
```

then ran `make arm.release hardfp=on library=shared -j4` and waited... when it finished I just did `sudo cp out/arm.release/lib.target/libv8.so /usr/lib/libv8.so` to have the lib available. I also did `sudo cp include /usr/` so that the include files are available.

Checking which gems I have installed I get

```
odroid@odroid-server:~/v8$ gem query --local

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (1.5.3)
ref (1.0.5)
```

So, I executed `sudo gem install libv8:3.16.14.3 -- --with-system-v8`

And you can see that it's installed

```
odroid@odroid-server:~/v8/out/arm.release$ gem query --local

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (1.5.3)
libv8 (3.16.14.3)
ref (1.0.5)
```

But now, when I go to the /home/git/gitlab folder an run

```
sudo -u git -H bundle install --deployment --without development test postgres aws
```

Fails again... then, I read about bundle config, so I run

```
sudo -u git -H bundle config build.libv8 --with-system-v8
sudo -u git -H bundle install --deployment --without development test postgres aws
```

And voilá!

but... then this

```
odroid@odroid-server:/home/git/gitlab$ sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:setup RAILS_ENV=production
ruby: symbol lookup error: /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/therubyracer-0.12.0/ext/v8/init.so: undefined symbol: _ZN2v82V821AddGCPrologueCallbackEPFvNS_6GCTypeENS_15GCCallbackFlagsEES1_
```

I tried copying everything from v8/out/arm.release/obj.target/tools/gyp to /usr/lib or even to /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/therubyracer-0.12.0/ext/v8/ without luck

Does anyone have any idea of how to make the v8 library available? I think that's the last bit of info I need to have it working.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeap! That's a common issue with libv8. But there is an alternative to install nodejs and ommit the `therubyracer` gem from the Gemfile. Check this [github issue](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/3849) and this [post](https://rainveiltech.com/posts/gitlab-6-3-with-apache-and-passenger-on-an-arm).

Steps:

1. Stop gitlab service
2. Edit Gemfile and remove the line `gem "therubyracer"`.
3. Move bundle config with: `mv /home/git/gitlab/.bundle/config{,.orig}`
4. Move Gemfile.lock with: `mv /home/git/gitlab/Gemfile.lock{,.orig}`
5. Run `sudo -u git -H bundle install --path vendor/bundle` to recreate the Gemfile.lock
6. Install nodejs
7. Restart gitlab service

Now, you have a new Gemfile.lock and **all** gems installed in vendor/bundle. If you want to save space, clean it up or sth, you can remove the vendor/bundle folder and run the known command for deployment:

```
sudo -u git -H bundle install --deployment --without development test postgres aws
```

This will pull only the relevant gems. Perhaps there is an easier way because now you have to have installed the devel packages for both mysql and postgres etc, but that's what came in mind right now.

Nodejs is a perfect replacement and should work without a problem. Since rails uses [execjs](https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#execjs), you can see in the Readme that node is supported as a javascript runtime.

Comment: If I tweak the gemfile (and the lock) I get `You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
your Gemfile. Run bundle install elsewhere and add the
updated Gemfile.lock to version control.` should I fork it and do the change on my repo?

Comment: Remove `/home/git/gitlab/.bundle/config` and `Gemfile.lock` and run just `bundle install` so that the Gemfile.lock gets recreated. Then run the known bundle command with the deployment flag. I'll also edit my comment above to be more clear.

Comment: I didn't really have luck... I have node.js running, deleted libv8 and therubyracer, generated the Gemfile.lock, added it to source control, ran bundle install and running the command to generate the tables ends with `rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- rack/mount`

Comment: I know it's against the SO policies... but after being stuck for 3 days, trying everything I could think about... that's exactly what I needed. Just installing node.js and changing the Gemfile.lock. THANKS!!!!!!!!

Comment: Glad you worked it out :)
I also tried it on Centos without a problem! Now you have to be careful during updates since you will have different Gemfile. You could create a different branch and run gitlab from there. Then on updates checkout to master/stable, merge it, checkout back to yours branch and do a rebase on master/stable.

Comment: You da real MVP guy !! Will Gitlab work like a charm without 'therubyracer  or it will cause some trouble?

Comment: I edit my answer above to reflect your concerns :)
Nodejs is a drop-in replacement of rubyracer, so fear nothing.

Comment: You mention it briefly, but not really as an required dependency: I needed the libmysqlclient-dev debian package for the gems to install.

Answer (score 1):

GitLab no longer has therubyracer as a dependency so changing Gemfile.lock is no longer necessary. You can just install nodejs and do the regular bundle install command.

Comment: That is correct... this means that the question is no longer relevant. I'm leaving the other answer as accepted, as it does answer the question

Answer (score -2):

Here are the options to create a GitLab installation: https://about.gitlab.com/installation/